# getting js error Uncaught TypeError: roundScore is not a function

Tags: javascript

Just trying to learn js and writing some mini game logic, but i am stuck because contantley get this error `Uncaught TypeError: roundScore is not a function`

Not to sure why this is as i do have the function in question:

```
var playerScore = 0;
var player = 0;
var roundScore = 0;

function rollDice() {
  var dice;
  dice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  return dice;
}

function playerTurn() {
  player === 0 ? player = 1 : player = 0;
}

function roundScore() {
  rollDice() !== 1 ? roundScore += rollDice() : (playerTurn(), roundScore = 0);
  return roundScore;
}

document.getElementById('rollDice').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('round-score-' + player).innerHTML = roundScore();
});
```

Can someone see why i am getting this error..? thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have both a function and a variable named `roundScore`. Because of the way JavaScript gets compiled, your functions get hoisted to the top of the file, which means `roundScore` is 0, not a function. So name either the function or the variable something else and you should be fine.

Comment: :) good catch, thank to you sorry to bother with silly mistakes

Comment: one question, so when js compiles the functions and variables get hoisted to the top of the file, but is it the functions that go above the variables in hoisting..? and i guess when the hoisting happens everything is set to `undefined`

Comment: Variables and functions both get hoisted to the top of their scope, but functions are always at the very top. There are loads of articles about this if you google some variation of 'js hoisting'. Here's one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript

Comment: If I could give you 10 upvotes i would... 2 days... 2... days. and you explain this so gracefully. I did have variables and functions the same name so make things easier for us to call. this solved it for me